# The iPhone automatically converts ipv4 to ipv6

Tags: ios, networking, vpn, ipv6

The iPhone that uses 5g receives ipv6 in a cellular Network.

In this situation, when I ping

`Ping 222.222.222.222`

iPhone convert it Automatically

`Ping 64:ff9b::dede:dede` (ipv6)

it looks like normal but

When a split tunnel is applied by configuring a VPN network, the network does not function properly because the network has been converted.

For example

I configured VPN Network like this:
`IP : 172.201.10.0 / Sub : 255.255.255.0 / GW : 172.201.10.1`

ping 172.201.10.1 must pass through the tunnel network.
However, ip does not pass through the tunnel because it has been converted to ipv6 (Like 64:ff9b::acc9:a01)

I don't know where to start.
Please advise how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's the iPhone and not the carrier? Most mobile carriers are now using only IPv6, and you are being converted to `IPv4-IPv6 Translat.`.

Comment: @RonMaupin Even if the carrier uses ipv6, the vpn configuration is using ipv4. Is it correct for vpn to use ipv6?